# A way around permission problems in R?

Tags: r

I'm starting to learn how to create maps in R and currently trying to get the code at the site below to work.

http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r-part-2/

code is:

```
map <- get_map("Atlanta", zoom=10)
ggmap(map)
```

I'm getting the error:
Error in download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") : 
  cannot open destfile 'ggmapTemp.png', reason 'Permission denied'

I believe this would be an issue because I'm on a work computer and how IT set the security settings. Is there away around this issue?

Thank you,

James

Comment: Read help file ... note the `filename` argument .... specify destination to a directory for which you have permission.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this fixed the problem.  outFiles<- "C:/test/" 
map <- get_map("Atlanta", zoom=10,filename=outFiles )
ggmap(map)

Comment: Rather than doing that for every call, you might consider changing your current working directory with `setwd()`.